# webclient does not support concurrent i/o operations, and I tried to add a bool

Tags: c#

I have tried to add a bool function so it will not download the second file before the first is finished. But when I do that my program locks! What can I do?

This is my code:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int total = listLink.Items.Count;
            total--;
            int current = -1;
            while (current < total)
            {
                if (completed == true)
                {
                    completed = false;

                    listLink.SelectedIndex = current + 1;
                    listSave.SelectedIndex = current + 1;
                    string download = listLink.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    string save = listSave.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    message = true;
                    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(download), save);
                    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
                    if (wc.IsBusy)
                    {
                        if (message == true)
                        {
                            //wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
                            message = false;
                        }
                    }
                    current++;
                }
                if (current == total)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Download Successful!", "Download Completed");
                    //completed = true;
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "% Advanced Download Manager";
    }

    private void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*if (shouldsay == true)
        {
            if (completed == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download Successful!", "Download Completed");
                shouldsay = false;
            }
            else if (completed == false)
            {

            }
        }*/
        completed = true;
    }
```

Comment: Start the second download in the DownloadFileCompleted event.

Comment: Yeah, but the users will change the amount of files to download..

Comment: Store each download URL in a `Queue<T>` and in the `DownloadFileComplete` event pop the next URL off the queue and download the file.

Comment: I tried to use the first answer you posted, and it works fine :D But i have a new problem, it says download completed several times i download a new file.............